# SWT DND want to drag text from table (which represents a virtual file) onto explorer. want destination path as String

Tags: java, swt, drag-and-drop

I have an application where user drags file onto table. The application splits file into several pieces and saves them to different places, and a String with the file name appears as text in the table. So far so good.

I want to then be able to drag that text String of a file name back onto an explorer window and just get the destination path as a String. I can handle the rest (combining the pieces back together again and saving to destination).

Not sure if I should be using `TextTransfer` since my source is a String, or `FileTransfer` because I want an absolute path

I could post code, but it is very spaghetti right now. Also I don't really know what I'm doing so I'm more looking to be pointed in the right direction than to have anyone just fix my code for me :)

Comment: I know this is a little old, but did you ever have any luck?

Comment: I've got the same problem.  I put together a little example code to make it easier for people to understand the problem and hopefully post a solution.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246242/swt-drag-to-explorer-windows-or-finder-os-x

Comment: No solution. Abandoned project. May redo in c#

Comment: I'm curious, did you find native APIs that present the destination folder?  If they exist, I'll take a shot at wrapping them up to make them work with SWT.